# How to simulate an out of disk space condition on iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I would like to test out some code I have in place to manage conditions where there's not enough free disk space to complete the operations.

However, I'm having trouble achieving such situation. I have tried to sync stuff from iTunes to fill up the devices, but either I get too much disk space free or the content will exceed the device capacity and iTunes will not allow the sync.

I'm sure there must be an easier and better strategy to test this situation on the device, but I can't figure it out. I would appreciate and tips or experiences you can share about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fill up the device until it's nearly at the limit in iTunes, then set a loop to copy a largish file into your Documents directory. Each time you copy it, give it a unique name (use UUID). Activate the loop to run a number of times with a control in your interface, or with a timer.

Comment: This is still a bit of a chore, but it really seems to be the only way to go; thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Here is a hint: To fill up your device via iTunes, you can create a large dummy file in your Mac's terminal using this command: `mkfile -n 1g ~/Desktop/LargeDummyFile`. This will create a file that is 1 gigabyte large. You can then transfer this file via iTunes to fill up the space as quick as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stupid idea.

1. Jailbreak your device
2. ssh into root
3. Execute a script (zsh?) that essentially implements this algorithm:

```
def logbomb(tries=5):
    try:
        for i in range(100):
            pass
            # write pow(2, i) many bytes into a log file in /private/var/tmp
    catch IOError:
        logbomb(tries - 1)
```

By the end you should get to a pretty stuffed private partition. Slightly increase the tries if that doesn't get close.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I do not wish to Jailbreak my testing devices. I should have specified that in the original question, sorry.